# Alamofire - Generic Network Call with Generic Response

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui, alamofire

```
class ApiManager {
        let  url = "https://15f1-61-246-140-18.in.ngrok.io/Legal251AppAPI_IOS/api/lgapp/index.php?parameter=sendotp"
       static let sharedInstance = ApiManager()
        
        func callingApi(signUp : myModel){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authkey": Secrets.AuthKey
    
        ]
            AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters:signUp , encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).response{
                response in debugPrint(response)
            }
            
           
        }   
    }
```

My response

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "message": "SMS IS SENT",
    "data": [
        {
            "status": 1,
            "number": "9999911144"
        }
    ]
}
```

My success response is coming in Data array

I tries to make the network class as generic but in that i am not able to make generic parameter for post the body in api

Here my signUp Model which my body of api

```
struct myModel: Encodable{
    var number : String = String()
    var action :String = String()
   
}
```

I need to achieve the generic class for networking I explored a lot but didn't got upto the mark answer

I hope here I will get

Thankyou In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API `responseJSON` is deprecated and just `response` returns `Data`.

The most recommended API however is `responseDecodable` which decodes the JSON directly into a model.

You can make your API call generic with

```
class ApiManager {
   let  url = "https://15f1-61-246-140-18.in.ngrok.io/Legal251AppAPI_IOS/api/lgapp/index.php?parameter=sendotp"
   static let sharedInstance = ApiManager()
    
    func callingApi<Input: Encodable, Output: Decodable>(signUp : Input, type: Output.Type){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authkey": Secrets.AuthKey
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, 
                  parameters: signUp, 
                  encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, 
                  headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: Output.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) { response in
                     switch response.result {
                         case .success(let result): print(result)
                         case .failure(let error): print(error)
                     }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `type` parameter pass the type of the root object for example `Response.self`

Comment: Hey Vadain , i wanted generic parameter and Reponse model.....signup is Body which is to be send to api....that I wanted generic and

Comment: Hey I have added my myModel too

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: ApiManager.sharedInstance.callingApi(signUp: model, type: ApiData) .....in type what i need to pass

Comment: Please read my answer to the end -> `ApiData.self`

Comment: what if, for some request, don't have any input and output?

Comment: @Frade You can make the parameters optional.

Comment: correct, but will not have any model "Input" that conform to protocol Encodable, and Output to Decodable.

Comment: @Frade It makes no sense to have no `Output` type as AF is going to decode the received data to that type. With regard to the `Input` type you can just omit it.